# Spring xml JNDI add sql script

Tags: sql, spring, jndi

I am new at Spring , and I have a table (customer) and a  **data.sql** script , like

```
#data.sql
insert into customer (id, name, age)
values ('1', 'Hope', 20);
insert into customer (id, name, age)
values ('2', 'Angel', 65);
```

when i use `EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean` i can use  `<property name="databasePopulator"`, for add my **data.sql** script

```
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean">
            <property name="databasePopulator" ref="populator"/>
            <property name="databaseType" value="HSQL"/>
        </bean>
        <bean id="populator" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator">
            <property name="scripts" value="data.sql"/>
        </bean>
```

but now, i decided use JNDI dataSource, i configure my spring xml file like

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="/jdbc/DataTest" />
```

my question is , how can add my **data.sql** script now my xml configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jdbc initialize

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="true">
    <jdbc:script location="data.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```